# Large Network Iterations - Parallelism?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am writing an algorithm to measure the robustness of a large network under independent attacks. The network has around 2000 nodes and it faces 10^8 attacks. Initially I implemented my soution in Matlab, but too many iterations(10^8) didn't work out. Every iteartions tries to rewire the network by improving robustness.

The problem with simple parallelism is that everytime the network gets rewired the new iterations works on the rewired network.

I am not sure how to achieve a high degree of parallelism here in order to run my algorithm efficiently. Currently with no parallelism I belive it will take about 1477 days.

Comment: What do you mean rewired Netowrk?

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration is taking about 1.25 seconds. (about 4 billion clock cycles) That sounds like a long time, there must be some opportunity to optimise what you are doing and reduce it to milli-seconds.  Optimising code can often improve performance greater than parrallelising it can. (as parrallelising code is limited by the amount of free hardware you have and the overhead of having co-ordinating multiple CPU/systems)

How much hardware do you have?  If your process is CPU bound, you will make the application at most N times faster if you have N CPUs.

Say you have enough hardware e.g. 2048 CPUs to play with and taking 1 day is acceptiable. Instead of assuming you need to have a completely faithful end to end test, you can start the network in different random/likely configurations.  Run 10^5 attacks on each network independantly and check your end state closingly matches a starting state of another run. i.e. you could notionally join the results together end-to-end.

---

Depending on how much memory you need you may find tower servers are the most cost effective.

You can buy a server with a Xeon Quad 2.5 GHz and 4 GB of memory for £354.  Thats a lot of power for the money.

However if you have access to an existing resource you may be better off. e.g. do you work for a company that has 1,000 desktops which are not used over night. ;)

Comment: I followed your advice of optimising code. It improves performance a lot. I look more into getting CPUs for my simulation.

Answer (score 0):

The way you formulate the problem, there seems to be no way to parallelize the iterations. Also, if the estimation of 1477 days is realistic, parallelizing will give you ~800 days on a two-core machine, which I guess is still inacceptable.

Instead, you could do the typical profiling workflow:

1. Identify a reasonably small piece of code that takes a long time to complete.
2. Optimize that piece of code by redesigning, rewriting in compiled language or tweaking.
3. Go to 1

If nothing of this gets you acceptable results, you will have to simplify your problem by doing less iterations or making some performance-critical assumptions.

Comment: I optimised some bits and improved performance considerably. I am looking into parallelizing my code now. Thanks!